# Failure during 2 backup jobs for one database

Tags: sql-server, backup, jobs

I have 2 jobs for one database.  One does a full backup every hour.  The other one is a transaction log backup every 15 minutes.

I've checked the job history.   It shows some failures at 16:00.  The detail is as follows:

[image]

Does that mean that 2 jobs can't run at the same time?

The error detail is:

> Message Executed as user: NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT.
>   Cannot open backup device 'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\AdventureWorksLT_from_Azure.bak'.
>   Operating system error 32(The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.).
>   [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 3201) BACKUP LOG is terminating abnormally.
>   [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 3013). The step failed.'

Could you please help me for that?

Comment: The error is clearly saying file is being locked by other program `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process` .. backing up to same file ?

Answer (score 3):

There are two possibilities that come to mind:

1. The full backup and the transaction log backup are trying to use the same file.

> 'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\AdventureWorksLT_from_Azure.bak'

2. Something else is locking the file i.e. tape backup

   I have had tape backups cause this problem for me. I had to wait until the tape backup finished then my SQL Agent backup job would work.

Comment: Thank you very much. I modify the transaction log back up to another file. The issue is gone!